# Translations problem when loading languages from json file

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have simple localization in my app. When I set languages manually in state it's works, but when I want to load translations from some json file I have a problem with second language and get standard error "Missing translationId: userId for language: cr", but code stays the same...
In constructor, when I use translations1,  this.props.addTranslation(this.state.translations1);
it works, but when I use  this.props.addTranslation(this.state.translations);
i get error

Can someone help me?

```
        constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        translations1: {
            pocetna: ['Početna', 'Почетна'],
            listaKorisnika: ['Lista Korisnika', 'Листа Корисника'],
            dodajKorisnika: ['Dodaj Korisnika', 'Додај Корисника'],
            userId: ['User ID', 'Усер ИД']
        },
        translations: []
    }
     this.props.initialize({
        languages: [
            {name: "Latinica", code: "lt"},
            {name: "Cirilica", code: "cr"}
        ],
        options: {
            renderToStaticMarkup,
            defaultLanguage: 'lt'
        }
    })

    this.props.addTranslation(this.state.translations);
    this.onChangeLanguage = this.onChangeLanguage.bind(this);
}
onChangeLanguage(_slag) {
    console.log('onChangeLanguage: ', _slag.value)
    this.props.setActiveLanguage(_slag.value);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getTranslations();
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('nextProps: ', nextProps.translations)
    this.setState({
        translations: nextProps.translations
    })
}

render() {

    const languageInSelect = [
        { label: 'Latinica', value: 'lt' },
        { label: 'Cirilica', value: 'cr' }
      ];

    return(
        <div className="sidebar"  style={{'backgroundImage': 'url(assets/img/sidebar-3.jpg)'}}
            data-color="purple" data-background-color="white" 
            data-image="../assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg">

        <div className="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul className="nav" >
                <li className="nav-item ">
                    <NavLink to="/pocetna" exact={true} className="nav-link"  activeStyle={{ 'backgroundColor': '#9c27b0', 'color':'white', 'fontWeight':'bold'}}>
                        <MaterialIcon icon="dashboard" />
                        {/* <i className="material-icons">dashboard</i> */}
                        <Translate id="pocetna">Početna</Translate>
                        {/* <p>Početna</p> */}
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item ">
                    <NavLink to="/listaKorisnika" exact={true} className="nav-link" activeStyle={{ 'backgroundColor': '#9c27b0', 'color':'white','fontWeight':'bold'}}>
                        <i className="material-icons">person</i>
                        <Translate id="listaKorisnika">Lista Korisnika</Translate>
                        {/* <p>Lista korisnika</p> */}
                    </NavLink>
                </li>

                <li className="nav-item ">
                    <NavLink to="/dodajKorisnika" className="nav-link" activeStyle={{ 'backgroundColor': '#9c27b0', 'color':'white','fontWeight':'bold' }}>
                        <i className="material-icons">person_add</i>
                        <Translate id="dodajKorisnika">Lista Korisnika</Translate>
                        {/* <p>Dodaj korisnika</p> */}
                    </NavLink>
                </li>

                <li className="nav-item ">
                    <Select 
                        onChange={this.onChangeLanguage}
                        options={languageInSelect}
                        defaultValue={{label: 'Latinica', value: 'lt'}}
                    />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>



    </div>
    )
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It is because `translations` variable is an array and if you want to use values from this array to call some function you should destructure it or map over it to get single values like `this.state.translations[0]` etc.

Comment: do you have another solution?

Comment: I fixed problem,all I need is to set translations in componentWillReciveProps, not in constructor, and you were correct for array..this.state.translations[0]. tnx a lot